# Introductory JavaScript chessboard printing program giving me problems

Tags: javascript

I have access to the answer to this exercise, but I can't figure out why the code below doesn't work. The task is to print to the console a chessboard of alternating "#" and spaces, and include a size variable to increase or decrease the size of the board. Why doesn't this code do that?

```
size = 8;

for (height = 0; height < size; height++) {
  width = 0;
  board = ""
  while (width < size) {
    board += ((height + width) % 2 === 0 ? "#":" ");
    width++;
  } board += "/n"
};

console.log(board);
```

Comment: Newline = `\n`. You have the slash flipped.

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues in your implementation:

1. You were using "/n" while you should use "\n" for a newline.
2. You were resetting your `board` variable to blank string in every iteration. So, in the end you only had a single line of chess row in your variable. You needed to take that variable outside the `for` loop.

```js
size = 8;
    
    var board = ""
    for (height = 0; height < size; height++) {
      width = 0;
      while (width < size) {
        board += ((height + width) % 2 === 0 ? "#":" ");
        width++;
      } board += "\n"
    };
    
    console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

You run into a couple of issues here:

Newline = '/n'

Also, you are clearing your board in every iteration. Move the `board = ""` outside the loop.:

```
size = 8;
board = "";
for (height = 0; height < size/2; height++) {
  width = 0;
  while (width < size) {
    board += ((height + width) % 2 === 0 ? "#":" ");
    width++;
  } 
  board += "\n";
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rgn9573g/2/